# Graph Between Steiner Tree and Complete Graph

Tags: optimization, graph, computational-geometry

Given a set points P in the plane, and given a threshold t, I'd like to compute a connected graph G to minimize the sum of the lengths of its edges, subject to the following constraints:

- The vertices of G contain all the points in P.
- For every pair of points u and v in P, their distance in G is no greater than t times their Euclidean distance.

When t=1, this problem is solved by constructing a complete graph on P. When t is infinite (or simply large enough), this problem is the Euclidean Steiner Tree Problem.

If there already a name for this problem, I'm curious what it is. More than that, does anyone have any suggestions for how to make an algorithm for this? Since it contains the Euclidean Steiner Tree Problem as a special case, it can't be simpler, so I'm not looking for anything particularly time efficient. Thanks!